# Keep important eigenvectors according to the important eigenvalues except one unimportant eigenvalue

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have an iteration whose steps extract a matrix with any possible dimension for example `3*3`, `6*6`, `10*10` , `4*4` ... . In any iteration I have eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix extracted, for example `{10^-6, 10^-4, 10^-3, 0.1, 0.4}`. I wish to keep eigenvectors corresponding to just `{10^-3, 0.1, 0.4}`.

In fact with the below code I could sort eigenvalues and corresponded eigenvectors:

```
{eivals, eivecs} = Eigensystem[matrix];
{eivals, eivecs}= {eivals[[#]], eivecs[[#]]} &@ Ordering[eivals];
```

But, when I want to use

```
desiredeigenvecs=Drop[eivecs, x]
```

I do not know how I insert a suitable x to keep eigenvectors according to the important eigenvalues except the first unimportant eigenvalues?!!

Comment: In this context, how do you define "important" and "unimportant"? It seems from your comment on @HenrikShumacher's post that *you* do not know what the threshold should be, so we can't possibly know either? Can you explain what you really mean here?

Comment: This critically depends on how **you define** important vs. unimportant. For instance, I could say that the only "unimportant" eigenvalue in your list is 10^-6; you, on the other hand, seem to have decided that the first unimportant one is 10^-3. That choice is arbitrary, so you have to come up with an appropriate rule yourself.

Comment: Yes, Your are completely right

Comment: I can get `10^-3` as threshold value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's get some sample data and generate a numerical eigensystem:

```
iris = Keys@ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "FisherIris"}, "Data"];
{evals, evecs} = Eigensystem@Correlation@iris;
```

`Correlation[iris]` above happens to be a $4\times 4$ matrix. You can then use e.g. `Pick` to extract the eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues with absolute value higher than your user-defined `threshold` using any one of the equivalent expressions below:

```
With[{threshold = 0.1}, {
  Pick[evecs, evals, _?(Abs[#] > threshold &)],
  Pick[evecs, Thread[Abs[evals] > threshold]],
  Pick[evecs, UnitStep[Abs[evals] - threshold], 1]
}]
```

Note also that, if your results are numerical, [`Eigensystem`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigensystem.html) is guaranteed to return eigenvalues ordered in decreasing absolute value, and the corresponding normalized eigenvectors in the same order as the eigenvalues to which they correspond (see *Details* section). Since you seem to imply that your results are numerical, there should be no need for further ordering of the results.

Answer (score 4):

```
x = Random`Private`PositionsOf[UnitStep[Abs[eivals] - threshold], 0]
```

Comment: Thanx, but how I determine threshold? it is not known.

Comment: I supposed you would consider eigenvalues of magnitude less than a certain threshold as unimportant. So _you_ have to know the size of `threshold`, not me.

Comment: Yes. You are right

Comment: So sorry for unconsidering

Comment: I can get  `10^-3` as threshold value. But I could not understand the mean of  `RandomPrivatePositionsOf`. Please let see for example I have `UnitStep[{1, 2, 3, 10^-3, 10^-4} - 10^-3]` which results in `{1, 1, 1, 1, 0}`. After that I must know how many `1` is in the last list for determining `x`!! it is correct?

Comment: `RandomPrivatePositionsOf[list, 0]` reads off the positions of all `0` in the list `List`. Like `Flatten[Position[list,0]]`, but faster.

Comment: But my mathematica cannot recognize that!!!

Comment: Oh, backticks are important: It has to be ``Random`Private`PositionsOf``. Just to be sure: What version of _Mathematica_ are you using?

Comment: So sorry I did not insert ` `Private` `. I inserted Private!! Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome.